# Change startDate with datepicker for bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker

I have a meeting  editing page. the user is allowed to create a new meeting, or they can get a list of meetings and once they select a meeting edit that meeting.

I am using http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/ for my datepicker

For the create meeting I want start date to be `new Date()`, and this works fine, however when I go to populate the form with the selected meeting, I can't reset the startDate.

Here is how I set up the datepicker

```
var datePicker = $("#dp1").datepicker({
        format: "mm/dd/yyyy",
        autoclose: true,
        startDate: new Date(),
    }).on("changeDate", function(e){
        startDate = new Date(e.date);
        // --- more code here --
    });
```

Then when a user clicks a meeting from the search results, I try to reset the start date but it doesn't work.

My latest try is:

```
$('#dp1').data('datepicker').setStartDate(new Date(selectedmeeting.startTime));
$('#dp1').datepicker({'setDate': new Date(selectedmeeting.startTime)});
```

Any ideas should I instantiate the picker differently  or is it on the population of the form?

Comment: You say reset the start date, do you mean set the date to the date of the meeting?

Comment: Are you just trying to set the value? `$("#dp1").val(selectedmeeting.startTime);`

Comment: when the page laods I want the form to only allow dates today and into the future. however if someone searches for an old meeting I want the date picker to use that date, but its before the stateDate I defined on load. What happens now is the blank form works fine, but when a user clicks on a result meeting the datepicker input either shows todays date or its blank.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly about your question
But maybe it will help you

```
var nowTemp = new Date();
var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getDate(), nowTemp.getMonth(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
$('#dp1').datepicker({ 
    autoclose: true,
    startDate: now
}).on('changeDate', function(e){
    $('#dpd1').datepicker('setStartDate', e.date);
});
```

It will change startDate every set a date.